# Bootstrap multilevel dropdown menu issue

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I am using a bootstrap template and I want to extend the dropdown menu to level 2. First level is working fine. I did the 2nd level dropdown by show/hide using javascript. Below is my Javascript. This works well with PC and laptop.

**But in mobile view it doesn't work properly.** When clicked/touched the 2nd level menu appears, but because of bs-toggle effect the menu closes. In the second click/touch it shows the 2nd menu as well. Looking for help to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){    

  // close all inner dropdowns when parent is closed
  document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .dropdown').forEach(function(everydropdown){
    everydropdown.addEventListener('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
      // after dropdown is hidden, then find all submenus
      console.log('document load');
        this.querySelectorAll('.submenu').forEach(function(everysubmenu){
          // hide every submenu as well
          everysubmenu.style.display = 'none';                 
        });
    })
  });

  function isMobileView() {
   console.log(window.innerWidth);
    return window.innerWidth < 850;
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu a').forEach(function(element){
   if(!isMobileView()){
      element.addEventListener('mousenter', function (e) {
         console.log('mouseover menu abc');
         let nextEl = this.nextElementSibling;
         console.log(nextEl);
         if(nextEl && nextEl.classList.contains('submenu')) {   
            // prevent opening link if link needs to open dropdown
            e.preventDefault();
            
            if(nextEl.style.display == 'block'){
               
               nextEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important');     
                     
            } else {
               
               nextEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:block !important');
               
            }

         }
      });

      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (e) {
         let nextEl = this.nextElementSibling;
         if(nextEl && nextEl.classList.contains('submenu')) {   
            if(nextEl.style.display == 'block'){
               nextEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important'); 
            }else{
               nextEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:block !important');
            }
         }
         
      });
   }else{
      element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         
         let nextEl = this.nextElementSibling;
         
         if(nextEl && nextEl.classList.contains('submenu')) {   
            // prevent opening link if link needs to open dropdown
            e.preventDefault();
            
            if(nextEl.style.display == 'block'){
             
               nextEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important');     
                   
            } else {
               
               nextEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:block !important');
               
            }

         }
      });
   }
    
  })
//}
// end if innerWidth
});
```

**Below is my HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-custom navbar-light sticky-top p-0">
         <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center px-4 px-lg-5">
            <!--<h1 class="m-0">Logo</h1>-->
            <img src="img/hikkspice-logo.png" height="60" width="180">
         </a>
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler me-4" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto p-4 p-lg-0">
               <a href="index.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
               <a href="about.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Who We Are</a>
               <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>                     
                     <div class="dropdown-menu bg-custom m-0">
                        <a href="products-cinnamon-spice.php?proname=Cinnamon Alba" class="dropdown-item">Ceylon Cinnamon Products &raquo;</a>
                           
                           <div class = "submenu dropdown-menu subitem1">
                              <a href="products-cinnamon.php" class="dropdown-item">Cinnamon Quills</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cinnamon Quillings</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cinnamon Powder</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cinnamon Oil</a>
                           </div>
                           
                        <a href="products-cinnamon-spice.php?proname=Cinnamon C5" class="dropdown-item">Ceylon Spices Products &raquo;</a> 
                           <div class = "submenu dropdown-menu subitem2">
                              <a href="products-cinnamon.php" class="dropdown-item">Black Pepper</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">White Pepper</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cardamom</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Nutmeg</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Nutmeg Mace</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cloves</a>
                           </div>                        
                    </div>
               </div>               
               <a href="history.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Cinnamon</a>
               <a href="health.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Health Benefits</a>
               <a href="contact.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <a href="quote.php" class="btn btn-custom py-4 px-lg-4 rounded-0 d-none d-lg-block">Get A Quote<i class="fa fa-arrow-right ms-3"></i></a>
         </div>
      </nav>
```

**This is my CSS for 2nd level submenu**

```
<style>
         @media (min-width: 320) and (max-width: 640px) {
            body {
    background-color: #de3163;
  }
         .subitem1{
         margin-top: -10px !important;
         }
         .subitem2{
         margin-top: -30px !important;
         }

         .dropdown-menu { position: absolute; }
         .nav-item .submenu{
         display: none !important;
         position: inline;
         left:100%; top:10px;
         }
         .nav-item .submenu-left{
         right:100%; left:auto;
         }
         .dropdown-menu > li:hover{ background-color: #f1f1f1 }
         .dropdown-menu > li:hover > .submenu{ display: block; }
         }

         @media all and (min-width: 992px) {
         .subitem1{
         margin-top: -60px !important;
         }
         .subitem2{
         margin-top: -30px !important;
         }

         .dropdown-menu { position: relative; }
         .nav-item .submenu{
         display: none !important;
         position: absolute;
         left:100%; top:10px;
         }
         .nav-item .submenu-left{
         right:100%; left:auto;
         }
         .dropdown-menu > li:hover{ background-color: #f1f1f1 }
         .dropdown-menu > li:hover > .submenu{ display: block; }
         }

         @media all and (min-width: 992px) {
    .dropdown-menu { position: relative;    }
    .nav-item .submenu{ 
        display: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        left:100%; top:10px;
    }
    .nav-item .submenu-left{ 
        right:100%; left:auto;
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li:hover{ background-color: #f1f1f1 }
    .dropdown-menu > li:hover > .submenu{ display: block; }
}   
/* ============ desktop view .end// ============ */

/* ============ small devices ============ */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu{
      margin-left:0.7rem; margin-right:0.7rem; margin-bottom: .5rem;
  }
}   
      </style>
```